# Is writing self closing tags for elements not traditionally empty bad practice?

Tags: xml, html, xhtml

I have noticed jQuery (or is it Firefox) will turn some of my `<span class="presentational"></span> into <span class="presentational" />`

Now my question is, is this okay to write my markup like this? Will any browsers choke on it?

Personally, I think it looks cleaner to do `<span class="presentational" />` if it's going to be empty.

Comment: AFAIK that space bf the slash came about as workaround for a bug in IE5, so that should be part of the past by now.—i'm happy i'm only writing HTML5 these days, and i have no qualms using `<x></x>` even when that tag is without content. i think everyone has a perfect right to be **happy** for every single annoying / confusing grammar 'feature' of `/(SG|XH|HT|X)ML/` they can leave behind for good; self-closing tags are just that. i think `<span class="presentational"></span>` does cleanly communicate that it is a tag with no content, and is universally and unequivocally understood as such.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I'm assuming your question has to do with the red trailing slash on self-closing elements when you view source in Firefox.  If so, you've stumbled into one of the most vehement, yet simultaneously passive aggressive debates in the browser maker vs. web developer wars. XHTML is NOT just about a document's markup.  It's also about how documents are meant to be served over the web.

Before I begin; I'm trying hard not to take sides here.

The XHTML 1.1 spec says that a web server should serve XHTML with a Content-Type of application/xhtml+xml.  Firefox is singling out those trailing slashes as invalid because your document is being served as text/html rather than application/xhtml+xml.  Take these two examples; identical markup, one served as application/xhtml+xml, the other as text/html.

http://alanstorm.com/testbed/xhtml-as-html.php

http://alanstorm.com/testbed/xhtml-as-xhtml.php

Firefox flags the trailing slash in the meta tag as invalid for the document served with text/html, and valid for the document served with application/xhtml+xml.

### Why this is Controversial

To a browser developer, the point of XHTML is you can treat your document as XML, which means if someone sends you something that's not valid, the spec says you don't have to parse it.  So, if a document is served as application/xhtml+xml and has non-well formed content, the developer is allowed to say "not my problem".  You can see that in action here

http://alanstorm.com/testbed/xhtml-not-valid.php

When a document is served as text/html, Firefox treats it as a plain old HTML document and uses the forgiving, fix it for you, parsing routines

http://alanstorm.com/testbed/xhtml-not-valid-as-html.php

So, to a browser maker, XHTML served as text/html is ludicrous, because it's never treated as XML by the browser's rendering engine.

A bunch of years ago, web developers looking to be more than tag monkeys (Disclaimer: I include myself as one of them) started looking for ways to develop best practices that didn't involved thrice nested tables, but still allowed a compelling design experience.  They/We latched onto XHTML/CSS, because the W3C said this was the future, and the only other choice was a world where a single vendor (Microsoft) controlled the defacto markup spec.  The real evil there being the *single vendor*, and not so much Microsoft.  I swear.

So where's the controversy? There are two problems with application/xhtml+xml.  The first is Internet Explorer.  There's a legacy bug/feature in IE where content served as application/xhtml+xml will prompt the user to download the document.  If you tried to visit the xhtml-as-xhtml.php listed above with IE that's likely what happened.  This means if you want to use application/xhtml+xml, you have to <s>browser sniff for IE</s>, check the Accepts header and only serve application/xhtml+xml to those browsers that accept it.  This is [not as trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351380/xhtml-what-are-the-problems-associated-with-serving-pages-with-content-applicat#351908) as it sounds to get right, and also went against the "write once" principle that the web developers were striving for.

The second problem is the harshness of XML.  This is, again, one of those flame prone issues, but there's some people who think a single bad tag, or single character improperly encoded shouldn't result in a user not seeing the document they want to.  In other words, yes, the spec says you should stop processing XML if it's not well formed, but the user doesn't care about the spec, they care that their cat's website is broken.

Adding even more gasoline to the issue is the XHTML 1.0 (not 1.1) spec says that XHTML documents *may* be served as text/html, assuming certain [compatibility guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines) are followed. Things like the img tag being self closing and the like.  The key word here is *may*.  In [RFC speak](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt), may means optional.  Firefox has chosen NOT to treat documents served with an XHTML doctype but a content type of text/html as XHTML.  However, the W3C validator will happily report these documents as valid.

I'll leave the reader to ponder the simultaneous wonder/horror of a culture that writes a document to define what they mean by the word *may*.

### Moving Forward

Finally, this is what the whole [HTML 5](http://blog.whatwg.org/category/weekly-review) thing is about.  XHTML became such a political hot potato that a bunch of people who wanted to move the language forward decided to go in another direction. They produced a spec for HTML 5.  This is currently being hashed out in the W3C, and expected to finish sometime in the next decade.  In the meantime, browser vendors are picking and choosing features from the in-progress spec and implementing them.

### Updates from the Comments

In the comments, [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31671/alex) points out that if you're going to sniff for something, you should check the Accept header to see if application/xhtml+xml is accepted by the user agent.

This is absolutely correct.  In general, if you're going to sniff, sniff for the feature, not for the browser.

Comment: Good summary, interesting testbed example. I confirm that IE6 doesn't want to display xhtml-as-xhtml. For those wondering, like me, the first two documents are correctly displayed by FF3 but in the View source of the first one, the slash is red...

Comment: PS.: I am aware of articles like http://www.webdevout.net/articles/beware-of-xhtml
What is your take? Serve XHTML as HTML? Stick to well formed (closing tags, quoting attributes...) HTML4?

Comment: My take is there's a cold war going on between browser vendors, and developers are stuck in the middle.  For new projects I'm leaning towards HTML 5, authored as well formed XML. However, most of my day-to-day is dealing with legacy code, and I haven't had a chance to see how useful HTML 5 is.

Comment: Instead of browser sniffing, I've always checked the user agents 'Accept' in the request headers to determine if I should send Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset = UTF-8

Comment: FWIW, when you write “Firefox has chosen NOT to treat documents served with an XHTML doctype but a content type of text/html as XHTML.”, please be aware that this was based on advice from the relevant W3C working group at the time: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/2000Sep/0024.html

Answer (score 20):

An addition to the other answers: in IE, having elements such as `<span />` in your mark-up **will cause all kinds of problems with DOM traversal methods in JavaScript**. Have a look at the following XHTML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show() {
            var span = document.getElementById("span");
            alert(span.innerHTML);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="show();">
<p id="p1">Paragraph containing some text followed by
           an empty span<span id="span"/></p>
<p id="p2">Second paragraph just containing text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is that when the page loads, the JavaScript will get a reference to the empty span and display its HTML contents. That will be an empty string, right? Not in IE it won't. In IE, you get all the content after the span in the whole document:

```
</P>
<P id=p2>Second paragraph just containing text</P>
```

Also, the second `<p>` shows up in the span's `childNodes` collection. That same `<p>` is also in the body's `childNodes` collection, meaning **a node can effectively have multiple parents**. This isn't terribly good news for scripts that rely on traversing the DOM.

I have also [blogged about this](http://tmik.co.uk/?p=184).

Comment: Nice. Note that this applies not just span but to the other inline elements as well. And is true whether you use <span /> or <span> (although the latter results in invalid XHTML). But **not** to the new HTML5 elements added using the HTML5 shiv. Using "document.createElement('meter')" and placing replacing the <span /> with <meter> has the same multiple parent effect, but replacing the <span /> with <meter /> creates the DOM you'd normally expect, because IE treats <xxx /> as a self closing tag when xxx is registered as an html tag name using document.createElement.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work when xxx is an existing HTML 4 tag name.

Comment: Any details on which IE versions suffer from this?

Comment: As your blog says, IE 6, 7, 8.  I've now tested that IE 9+ (and Edge) return empty string.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. It is. It'll cause problems in certain cases for old browsers.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js' />
```

In this case, the old browser might not understand that `<script>` tag has ended.

Comment: Does IE6 come under an old browser? I'm only looking for support from IE6, firefox 2, safari 2, chrome +++

Comment: I think if you consider standard complaint-ness, it's VERY OLD!

Comment: Haha, I know. At least it seems some developers are finally putting their foot down and dropping support.

Comment: I know from recent painful experience that MSIE6 *definitely* chokes on this.

Comment: Some newer browsers do too. `<script src="/scripts/jquery.js" /><script>/* In Firefox (tested in 3.5 and 3.6), this script does not run, and is not parsed as part of the DOM; the earlier script tag's self-closing slash is marked as red in "view source", and this script's opening tag is displayed as text content of the earlier script, ignored by the parser. */ alert('test 1');</script><script>/* In firefox, this script does run, and is parsed as part of the DOM */ alert('test 2');</script>` Interestingly, WebKit used to behave quite similarly, but seems to forgive self-closed `<script>`s now.

Comment: @Mehrdad:  LOL @ your use of "COMPLAINT-ness", esp. regarding IE6 (DIEDIEDIE)

Comment: Recent iterations of Google Chrome also appear to treat <script src="..." /> as invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Served as application/xhtml+xml, <span /> means create a span element with no content.

Served as text/html, <span /> means create a span element where the contents of the element follow this tag until the </span> tag is encountered, or another tag (or EOF) that implicitly closes the element is encountered. i.e. in this case <span /> means the same as <span>.

Aside: HTML 5 defines both and HTML and XHTML serializations, so it doesn't affect this issue one way or another. It does require, like XHTML 1.1, that XHTML be served as application/xhtml+xml, unlike XHTML 1.0. In effect though, this changes nothing as all browsers treat any version of XHTML served as text/html as tag soup.

Comment: Just to be clearn, I think you mean "Served as text/html, <span> means create ..." rather than "<span/>".  Self-closing elements are an XML-ism that HTML parsers doesn't comprehend well.

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I said. The point is that in text/html <span /> isn't a self closing element, it's an opening tag for the element. All the HTML parsers used by browsers in current use treat this the same way.

Answer (score 2):

See the note on the subject form the XHMTL working group: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/

In short — it is fine if your XHTML is going to be treated as XHTML. If you are going to pretend it is HTML (which you need to do if you want it to be loaded by Internet Explorer (including version 8, latest at the time of writing) then you have to jump through hoops).

The hoops are sufficiently annoying that I would recommend most people stick to HTML 4.01.

Answer (score 2):

Also worth noting is that an `<?xml ...?>` declaration before the doctype throws IE into quirks mode.

Comment: eyelidlessness... where have you been on Stack Overflow? Thanks for the answer +1

Comment: @alex, I've been contracting and have plenty of work. I still pop my head in here and there. :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be explicitely said that there are no self-closed tags in HTML, so whenever a browser decides to treat your XHTML as HTML, it will not recognize that the tag is closed. Not a problem for tags that don't have to be closed in HTML, like `<img>`, but obviously bad with tags like `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's not a problem to use shorthand for empty elements, but there are some exceptions where it can cause problems.

`<script>` is an important one that needs to be closed with `</script>` to avoid issues.

Another is `<meta>` which works much better with spiders written as `<meta></meta>` instead of `<meta />`

Not exactly the question, but related, in terms of formatting, versions of IE have problems with just empty elements such as `<div></div>` or `<div />`.  In this case, `<div>&nbsp;</div>` is required to maintain the formatting.

Comment: meta IS an empty element.  In HTML (or XHTML served as HTML) it MUST be written as <meta />!  In true XHTML it doesn't matter.

Comment: @thomas: Don't all tags have to be closed (including self-closure) in XHTML?

Comment: @Casebash all elements have to be closed in XHTML, but there's two ways of closing an element - with a separate closing tag or self-closing with a slash at the end of the opening tag.  In HTML and HTML-compatible XHTML ie XHTML1, however, some elements, namely elements whose content model is EMPTY such as img, br, and meta, must NOT have a separate closing tag.  Non-EMPTY elements like div do need a separate closing tag.  The above answer is completely wrong about <meta></meta> - this is not allowed, and must be self-closed ie <meta /> in XHTML1 or <meta> (no closing tag) in HTML.

Comment: you and I both know that almost everyone who uses XHTML 1.0 uses it as if it is HTML, and therefore the rules of HTML apply.  XHTML-specific syntax may validate, but it won't work if it's not HTML-compatible.  I actually did qualify what I said by saying "in HTML and HTML-compatible XHTML".  Now, if you were to serve XHTML as XML, then sure you could do <meta></meta> if you chose.  But you can't really do that on today's web anyway.  Let's not confuse people.