# Adding script JS in HTML problem

Tags: javascript, html

somebody can answer me why occur this problem?

With the following code my site only works in Chrome, on IE7/8 and Firefox show me only the background:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Site Title</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js" />
</head>
...
```

And with this code works in Chrome, IE7/8 and Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>CSite Title</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

Viewing the code that don't works in Firebug I see that the file 'functions.js' is not called, I don't understand, why don't works with "`<script />`" and with "`<script></script>`" works?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from this ticket ([Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work))

***(please note that in the referenced ticket the accepted answer is not actually correct)***

> Note that IE does not support XHTML
>   parsing. Even if you use an XML
>   declaration and/or an XHTML doctype,
>   IE still parses the document as plain
>   HTML. And in plain HTML, the
>   self-closing syntax is not supported.
>   The trailing slash is just ignored,
>   you have to use an explicit closing
>   tag.
>
> Even browsers with support for XHTML
>   parsing will still parse the document
>   as HTML unless you serve the document
>   with a xml mime type. But in that case
>   IE will not display the document at
>   all!

Comment: Note that the accepted answer on the other question is in fact wrong – or at least it’s not the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: yeah, should have pointed that out. the answer i quoted was not actually the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Because `<script>` tag MUST have a closing tag in HTML4

Another source for information: [XHTML - Is writing self closing tags for elements not traditionally empty bad practise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/xhtml-is-writing-self-closing-tags-for-elements-not-traditionally-empty-bad-pra/348818#348818)

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) requires that you have an end tag for a script element.  The former is not valid HTML, while the latter is.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the tags I think is best viewed in code and also I think a good practice. If you follow this tip will no longer have such problems.