# Correct way to leave empty elements in xhtml?

Tags: html, xhtml

I've been experimenting with xhtml and now I'm wondering that is there a valid/correct way to add empty elements.

Short question, but here's the two ways I've been using:

```
<div> </div>
<div>&#32;</div> <!-- Same as space -->
```

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that the answer I've given below doesn't help you too much - could you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I just wanted to some expert around here tell me, which way is the valid way to add empty element. I need empty elements for many effects but no need to make the code unvalid. I've been told that it's not recommendable to leave any element just empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div />
```

is valid XTHML for an empty element: i.e. *self-closing*. Same as

```
<div></div>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks :-) This is actually the thing I was looking for.

Comment: @Martti: Highly inadvisable in a browser though. IE treats always XHTML as HTML and will not parse that correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/xhtml-is-writing-self-closing-tags-for-elements-not-traditionally-empty-bad-pra/1573341#1573341

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
<div></div>
```

A space inside an element is not "nothing" - it's a text node which makes the element non-empty.