# jQuery html() and self-closing tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

While creating self-closed elements with jQuery html() the following issue happens:

```
$('#someId').html('<li><input type="checkbox" /></li>')
```

will create

```
<li><input type="checkbox"></li>
```

It closes correctly the `<li>` tag but not the `<input>`

It seems to be an issue from innerHTML which is used in the html() function.

I have looked everywhere and found a solution for this but the page is not available anymore as you see in: http://dev.jquery.it/ticket/3378

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: can't you just change it to 
$('#someId').html('<li><input type="checkbox"></input></li>')

Comment: You're using the XHTML closing method.  Is that what you want or just HTML?

Comment: You shouldn't self-close html

Answer (score 9):

To clarify, this is valid HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

and this is valid XML (including XHTML):

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

but it is *not* valid HTML. That being said, most browsers will probably accept it anyway (but the document will fail validation if that means anything to you).

`html()` uses `innerHTML`. In IE and possibly other browsers this has issues because XHTML is still modeled as an HTML DOM. See [Internal IE-HTML DOM still isn’t XHTML compliant](http://ajaxian.com/archives/internal-ie-html-dom-still-isnt-xhtml-compliant).

Basically, there is very little reason to use XHTML. It's a cross browser nightmare. For a detailed synopsis as to why see [XHTML - Is writing self closing tags for elements not traditionally empty bad practise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/xhtml-is-writing-self-closing-tags-for-elements-not-traditionally-empty-bad-pra), particularly the first answer.

Comment: But it's not correct XHTML - "In XHTML, the <input> tag must be properly closed, like this <input />."

Comment: @Pedro my advice is "don't use XHTML". It's a bit of a cross-browser nightmare. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/xhtml-is-writing-self-closing-tags-for-elements-not-traditionally-empty-bad-pra

Comment: Nice link... I was about to post it!

Comment: Thanks cletus I had read it before and I guess I have to make the transition sooner or later but since it seems to exist a solution I would like to know it.

Answer (score 3):

In the era of HTML5, one might argue that `<input type="checkbox">` and `<input type="checkbox" />` are equally valid representations of the same void element.

While that is true, the reason `innerHTML` still serializes void elements without the `/>` is twofold:

- A void element is a void element regardless of how *you* represent it to the browser. By the time the browser has constructed the element, its markup is irrelevant, and as far as the DOM is concerned, what it is is an `input` element of type checkbox. The only place the element's "tag" is relevant is its `tagName` property, and [even that has its own quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811426/why-does-the-tagname-dom-property-return-an-uppercase-value/11811518#11811518).
- There is no reason whatsoever for a browser to *begin* serializing a void element with the `/>` syntax when HTML5 itself, by virtue of being based on HTML, not XML, doesn't require it. Doing so just because it's equally valid to use the `/>` syntax needlessly breaks compatibility with legacy sites for absolutely zero gain (because the presence of the `/>` doesn't change the meaning of the output in any way). Which brings us back to cletus's answer distinguishing between HTML markup and XHTML markup.

`innerHTML`, and by extension `jQuery.html()`, was designed to give you an HTML representation of an element's contents *from the DOM*. It is *not* designed to give you the HTML markup that the browser used to construct the element in the DOM. You cannot "fix" this because there is nothing to fix to begin with. What you need to do, is avoid relying on an element's `innerHTML` for anything other than perhaps the occasional debugging session.

See also: [Nested <p> tag auto-closing/opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43395847/nested-p-tag-auto-closing-opening/43396701#43396701)