# jQuery replaces <br/> with <br>

Tags: jquery

Why does jQuery replace `<br/>` with `<br>` when using the `.html()` function?

When I try to do the following:

```
var q = $('<div></div>');
q.html('a<br/>b');
```

The result in the console will be

```
<div>
"a"
<br>
"b"
</div>
```

Why is this happening please? How can I disable this "feature"? I'm in a situation where

- tags not ending with /> are considered double
- unclosed double(pair) tags result in bad things

Thanks a lot for advice!

Edit: I am using jQuery 2.0.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery html() and self closing tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557295/jquery-html-and-self-closing-tags)

Comment: Unless you're using XHTML, the `<br>` element doesn't need a `/`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element

Comment: I need it to stay exactly the way I wrote it @JamesDonnelly.. I need to find a workaround for this :(

Comment: More specifically, `<br/>` is invalid HTML. It's not about proper form, acceptable form, etc, it is literally invalid.

Comment: If you really really super really need ... : https://github.com/stimpy77/xhtml.js

Answer (score 0):

In non-XHTML files, the proper form **is** `<br>`, not `<br/>`

> Tag omission: Must have a start tag, and must not have an end tag. In XHTML
>   documents, write this element as `<br/>`.

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

Answer (score 0):

When you give an HTML string to the `jQuery()` function, it uses the browser's HTML parser to convert it to DOM elements. When you later view it, you get the canonical form used by the browser, which may not be the same notation you originally used. Since `<br>` and `<br/>` are equivalent, the browser parses them into the same DOM. The information about which form you originally used is lost in this translation.