# jQuery removes slash from self-closing tags

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I found out that jQuery appears to be removing the closing slash from a self-closing XHTML tag when inserting this tag through .append(), .prepend() and other ways, which results in invalid XHTML which - on its turn - results in mangled markup.

The following code, for example:

```
$('body').append('<input type="text" id="test" value="test" />');
```

Results in the following:

```
<input id="test" value="test" type="text">
```

While the expected output is:

```
<input id="test" value="test" type="text" />
```

I am using **DOCTYPE:XHTML5**  and **Chrome** as a browser

Comment: I haven't used xhtml in quite some time, but is that even a valid doctype?

Comment: which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Did XHTML5 ever become a recommendation? Did it not just die silently? Edit: [Interesting](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149839/is-xhtml5-dead-or-is-it-just-an-synonym-of-html5).

Comment: That has nothing to do with jQuery, it is the browser that does it. What difference does it make?

Answer (score 0):

As XHTML does not support raw modification of codes & these functions: `document.write` or `innerHTML`, jQuery uses these functions to insert contents, thus compatibility errors will be prompted in the browsers.

Instead, you can create contents by:

```
document.createElement('div');
// bla bla bla
```

My suggestion would be changing the doctype to HTML5 to avoid this issue, unless you really need XHTML doctype.

Reference: [XHTML does not support docwrite](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite)

Comment: I could not use CreateElement as i want to append all input tags to div element which is draggable inside that div. how can i forcefully make that as self closing tags?

Comment: you can't in XHTML context. How about changing to HTML5 doctype instead?

Comment: @Unknown the browser knows it is a self closing tag... what is the specific problem with allowing browser to do what it wants to with it?

Comment: HTML5 gives same problem

Comment: @Unknown and you have not clarified why it is a problem

Comment: Actually i want to convert that this input tag in json format by using http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/

Comment: @Unknown HTML5 should have no problem with jQuery. I always use it to modify the contents.

Comment: How can i make forcefully this as self closing tag in OUTPUT?

Comment: there's no point to use XHTML and force adding self-closing tag in output. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557295/jquery-html-and-self-closing-tags)

Comment: A doctype does not do anything for the kind of file. The only thing that really makes a difference in XHTML vs HTML is the file type.

Comment: but XHTML will trigger error in browser but HTML5 won't.