# Nested <p> tag auto-closing/opening

Tags: html

I'm seeing some weird behavior around nested `<p>` tags. See [this](https://jsbin.com/ripaxe/edit?html,js,output) for the test case.

Given:

```
<p>
  <p>
    <p>
      <p>
        <p>
          <p>
          </p>
        </p>
      </p>
    </p>
  </p>
</p>
```

In Chrome, this results in

```
<p>
  </p><p>
    </p><p>
      </p><p>
        </p><p>
          </p><p>
          </p>
        <p></p>
      <p></p>
    <p></p>
  <p></p>
<p></p>
```

That is, it closes opening tags and opens closing tags. I've heard (of course) of "self-closing tags"; I've never heard of "self-opening tags".

IE11 does it a different (and arguably, even wronger) way:

```
<p>
  <p>
    <p>
      <p>
        <p>
          <p>
          </p>
        <p></p>
      <p></p>
    <p></p>
  <p></p>
<p></p>
```

So it does not auto-close opening tags, but it does auto-open close tags, resulting in an unbalanced DOM tree.

Anyway, I'm curious what the proper path to address this; should I open issues on Chrome and IE bug trackers? I'm not particularly well versed in the W3C specs, where would I go to try and find the "correct" behavior (I'm not aware of any tags apart from `<p>` that exhibit this behavior, although I haven't done extensive testing)?

For what it's worth, I realize nesting `<p>` tags is invalid; this is a result of a third party library that I am working to address with them, I just found this to be bizarre behavior).

EDIT: I was wrong about IE: see https://jsbin.com/ripaxe/5/edit?html,js,output. Turns out `innerHTML` is browser dependent. Didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test case uses innerHTML to display the serializations of your markup. Unsurprisingly IE tends to do things differently to other browsers, but neither browser's representation of your markup is wrong *per se*.

Chrome (and Firefox) inserts explicit `</p>` end tags to show exactly where each `<p>` start tag terminates. Each start tag terminates immediately before the next start tag (except the last one, which is terminated by its end tag). Notice that the whitespace is enclosed *within* each pair.

But the explicit end tags are not needed, and IE simply chooses not to insert end tags to match any of the start tags for that reason. That doesn't mean that there is any nesting going on — all of the `p` elements are still siblings, and you can verify this with the fact that `document.querySelector('p p')` returns null and `document.querySelector('p:nth-child(11):last-child')` returns the element represented by the very last `</p>` end tag in all browsers.

The end tags that are in your original markup are preserved, of course, but the reason all but the first end tag are matched with their own start tags (*without* enclosing the whitespace this time) is described in [Why does a stray </p> end tag generate an empty paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570902/why-does-a-stray-p-end-tag-generate-an-empty-paragraph) — in short, it's specced by HTML5 for consistency with legacy browser behavior.

The end tag for the `p` element being optional is also the reason why both representations are equally valid (and, in fact, functionally equivalent) HTML fragments. So, there is nothing wrong with what IE is doing, but it does create headaches for authors relying on the innerHTML property simply because it does things differently.

But this is why you shouldn't rely on innerHTML.

Comment: I realize that it ends up not being nested because of the auto-closing, even though the source markup tries to make it so. The link you added is useful, though--it at least explains the auto-opening. Is this unique to `<p>`? And if I understand correctly, you're saying IE ends up having the same effective DOM structure as Chrome, it's just that its `innerHTML` displays it without? That seems right; I used `XMLSerializer` instead and the tree looks right in IE too. Thanks, I didn't realize that `innerHTML` is not normative.

Comment: @Turner Hayes: Yes, it's unique to the p element. Similar behavior exists for the br element, but br is a void element, meaning it cannot have end tags in the first place, so I don't think it counts. Yes, the fragments <p><p> (two start tags) and <p></p><p></p> (two pairs of start and end tags) are equivalent, and not because of the way browsers treat them but because the HTML syntax says they are.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bug. `<p>` elements cannot be nested within other `<p>` elements as you've said.

Chrome is attempting to *fix* your code by closing your `<p>` tags for you, and is thus generating this markup. I'd suggest raising a bug report with the third-party library you're using instead as this isn't a browser-specific problem.

Comment: Right, I get that. It's invalid HTML. What's weird to me is that a) it's also auto-_opening_ tags and b) the behavior is inconsistent between browsers (and in IE11's case, resulting in an unbalanced DOM tree). Maybe the behavior is undefined in the specs? I don't know, but this behavior doesn't seem to happen for all tags (in particular, the self-opening tags).

Comment: Chrome is treating `<p><p>` as `<p></p><p>`. It also treats a standalone `</p>` as `<p></p>`, therefore your 6 nested `<p>` elements turn into 11 `<p>` non-nested elements. This is all part of Chrome attempting to fix your code for you. IE attempts to fix the code for you as well, but in it's own different way (as you're well aware). The onus here lies with the third-party library though, not the browsers. The browsers could quite easily refuse to render the page and give an error about invalid HTML, but it tries to render it in its own way.

Comment: @Turner Hayes: Does IE11's behavior actually result in an unbalanced tree? Did you verify that the p elements are actually nested as opposed to IE simply not displaying the end tags?

Comment: As to why they add start tags, see [Why does a stray </p> end tag generate an empty paragraph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570902/why-does-a-stray-p-end-tag-generate-an-empty-paragraph)

Comment: "The browsers could quite easily refuse to render the page and give an error about invalid HTML" You're probably thinking of XHTML, where browsers are *required* to refuse to render pages that are either not well-formed or invalid.

Comment: You're right; replaced innerHTML with `XMLSerializer` and the tree is fine: https://jsbin.com/ripaxe/5/edit?html,js,output