# Equivalent of "parentNode" in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I wrote some code that modifies the images on a webpage.  Works with firefox and safari.  But tryingto get it to work with Internet explorer has got me stumped.  What is the equivalent of "parentNode" in explorer?  Or how does one trick it into working?

```
images = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
parms = {};

for (a=0;a < images.length;a++){
    parent = images[a].parentNode; // <-- What to substitute for explorer?
    parms[a] = {};
    parms[a].bigsrc=parent.getAttribute("href");
    parms[a].w_o = images[a].width;
    parms[a].h_o = images[a].height;
    parms[a].IsBig = false;
    parms[a].loaded = false;
    images[a].border=0;
    parent.setAttribute("href","javascript:MakeBig('"+a+"')");
}
```

Comment: Just some general comments: use `var` to declare `images`, `parms`, `a` and `parent` locally; don't use `setAttribute` to set `href`, use `parent.href` instead (IE freaks out); you probably want `parms` to be an array (instead of a general object): `var parms = [];`; you probably want to set `images[a].style.border = "none"` instead of the `border` attribute, which is [obsolete](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html#img.attrs.border).

Comment: Could you provide some HTML so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: An example of the (works in firefox but not IE) code is here:
http://woodgears.ca/workshop/jacques/min.html

It's a cool image zooming effect, if only I could make it work with explorer (or opera, for that matter)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is with the assignment of the parentNode to a var called "parent." This seems to be a reserved word in IE that breaks the code. Change the var name and it should work.

Comment: Thanks.  That fixed it.  If only IE had given me a useful error message to that effect.

Comment: `parent` is **not** a reserved word. Had you used `var parent = images[a].parentNode;` it would have been fine. `parent` is a host object that provides a reference to the window object's parent frame and is apparently (and legally) not settable in IE, and `parent = images[a].parentNode;` attempts to set it.

Comment: Ahh this saved me a lot of hassle - thank you! I do think the answer should be edited to reflect it's not a reserved word, however it's still the correct answer in my view.

Answer (score 3):

`parentNode` works fine in IE (except in [certain cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/xhtml-is-writing-self-closing-tags-for-elements-not-traditionally-empty-bad-pra/1573341#1573341), very likely irrelevant here). The error is almost certainly elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Except that explorer fails on the "parentNode" statement, so the rest of the code doesn't even get to run.

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself, **`parentNode` is supported and works correctly in IE**. The problem is elsewhere. If you provide some HTML we might be able to tell you where.

Comment: Tim is correct that the problem is elsewhere. See my latest answer for where I think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the parentNode to be an anchor? It looks like you're trying to just wrap the image in a link. If that's correct, what might work as an alternative is adding an onclick to the image itself, and setting a hand cursor. That could create the appearance of the image being a link without you having to care what the parentNode is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "anchor".  I'm just trying to change the link that gets pointed to when the image is clicked.

Comment: Anchor is the tag used to create a link - that's why when you're making a link in HTML, the tag is 'a.'

So rather than trying to use Javascript to modify the anchor tag that surrounds the image, why not instead modify the image's own onclick? Again, that will allow you to avoid having to care what the parentNode is