# Multiple <script> tags and <!-- //required for FF3 and Opera -->

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

I've used Spring Roo to generate a basic web project.  The UI is JSP based, with a Tiles layout.  Looking at the default layout code, I noticed that  tags were defined as follows:

```
<script src="${dojo_url}" type="text/javascript" ><!-- //required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
<script src="${spring_url}" type="text/javascript"><!-- //required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
<script src="${spring_dojo_url}" type="text/javascript"><!-- //required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
```

If I take out the comments between the script tags, the resulting HTML in Firefox contains the first  tag but not the others.  If I put the comments back in the resulting HTML is correct.

My question is: **Why is this the behavior?**

The ([documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp)) for the script tag doesn't mention that it needs to include any sort of data content.  Is this a browser issue (as implied by the comment) or is it a JSP or Spring issue?

**Returned HTML and browser output** 
cURL results look the same regardless of comments being there or not:

```
<head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <link href="/student-cloud-app/static/styles/login.css;jsessionid=FFED09C524087878AEF09142A6A6F375" media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/student-cloud-app/static/images/favicon.ico;jsessionid=FFED09C524087878AEF09142A6A6F375" rel="SHORTCUT ICON" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/student-cloud-app/resources/dojo/dojo.js;jsessionid=FFED09C524087878AEF09142A6A6F375"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/student-cloud-app/resources/spring/Spring.js;jsessionid=FFED09C524087878AEF09142A6A6F375"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/student-cloud-app/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js;jsessionid=FFED09C524087878AEF09142A6A6F375"></script>
    <title>
      Sample App
    </title>
</head>
```

In fact, doing a View Source from Firefox looks the same whether the comments are there or not:

```
<head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org" />
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <link href="/student-cloud-app/static/styles/login.css" media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/student-cloud-app/static/images/favicon.ico" rel="SHORTCUT ICON" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/student-cloud-app/resources/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/student-cloud-app/resources/spring/Spring.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/student-cloud-app/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js"></script>
    <title>
      Sample App
    </title>
</head>
```

But if I turn on Firebug and examine the HTML tree, with comments removed there is a single script element and it contains an error message:

> Failed to load source for: http://localhost:8080/student-cloud-app/resources/dojo/dojo.js

and I get the blank page instead of a login form.  If I put the comments back in, Firebug reports all the script tags, no errors, and the page displays the login form.  Disabling Firebug has no effect on whether or not the page renders correctly; no comments = blank page, comments = correctly rendered page.

**Update:**
The actual  tags that were being returned were self-closing.  HTML tidy was fixing that issue.  The self-closing script tag is what was actually causing the problem.

**Update 2: Example HTML**
Here is HTML with properly closed script tags that works in a browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <link href="/student-cloud-app/static/styles/login.css"
    media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/student-cloud-app/static/images/favicon.ico"
    rel="SHORTCUT ICON" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>Student Cloud</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <form method="POST"
      action="/student-cloud-app/static/j_spring_security_check"
      name="f">
        <table align="center" class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="j_username">User name:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="j_username" type="text"
              id="j_username" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="j_password">Password:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="j_password" type="password"
              id="j_password" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="login_button" colspan="2">
              <input value="Login" type="submit" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the exact same HTML, except with self-closing script tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <link href="/student-cloud-app/static/styles/login.css"
    media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/student-cloud-app/static/images/favicon.ico"
    rel="SHORTCUT ICON" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/ajax.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
    <title>Student Cloud</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <form method="POST"
      action="/student-cloud-app/static/j_spring_security_check"
      name="f">
        <table align="center" class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="j_username">User name:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="j_username" type="text"
              id="j_username" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="j_password">Password:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="j_password" type="password"
              id="j_password" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="login_button" colspan="2">
              <input value="Login" type="submit" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Saved as .html files, the first example displays correctly in a browser, the second does not.

Comment: Can you paste the actual output (retrieved with `curl` or some-such instead of a browser)?

Comment: I've never seen or heard of this behavior. I agree that the way to investigate the problem is to look at the actual generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the comments were in place, the `<script>` tags in the generated HTML had a closing tag of `</script>`.  When those comments were removed, the tag was self closing.

Apparently self-closing script tags are [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/xhtml-is-writing-self-closing-tags-for-elements-not-traditionally-empty-bad-pra/348767#348767) in most browsers.  Thanks to thenduks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Not really. Every browser that supports XHTML supports self-closing script tags correctly.

Comment: I've verified in both FF3 and IE8 that with everything else being equal, empty script tags work but self closing ones do not.  I'm not suggesting that XHTML doesn't support any self closing tags, I'm saying it doesn't support self closing script tags.

Comment: you may not be working with a real XHTML environment. Make sure you get the DOCTYPE right so that you don't trigger HTML and/or quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

Are you properly removing the comments? It could be that you're removing just too many or too few comment openings/closings. Do you have exactly this?

```
<script src="${dojo_url}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${spring_url}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${spring_dojo_url}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure that you remove the same number of `<!--` and `-->` blocks.

Comment: The comments are being properly removed.

Comment: Can you please paste the block of HTML that you end up with?

Comment: The code has been pasted above.  Maybe I'm just missing something dumb.