# Who does my script tag effect the page rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <script type="text/javascript" href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js" />
        <title>JQuery Demo 1</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #box
            {
                background-color: #ff0000;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">----Text----!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I include the Jquery file from Google, the div "box" stops being red.  When I remove the JQuery file, it becomes red again.  WHY?

Comment: Also, when I remove:   <script type="text/javascript">


        </script>  The div disappears completely!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try *not* using self closing syntax for your `script` element, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
```

...and the correct attribute to point to a script file is `src`, not `href`.

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zsTB/).

Comment: Thanks, solves the problem.  I'd like to know why this happen, if you don't mind. :)

Comment: @Tim, I was a full *60+ seconds* too late...those darn high-rep users and their ninja ways... =)

Comment: @Tim You can't answer *all* the `[javascript]` questions :P

Comment: you people rock for helping me so quickly!!

Comment: @the_archer It is one of those quirks I believe - apparently *the old browser might not understand that `<script>` tag has ended.* [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/xhtml-is-writing-self-closing-tags-for-elements-not-traditionally-empty-bad-pra/348767#348767).

Comment: Not a browser quirk. The script element *hasn't* ended.

Comment: As the script element is not defined as having an EMPTY content model, using the abbreviated empty element syntax won't work: "Given an empty instance of an element whose content model is not EMPTY (for example, an empty title or paragraph) do not use the minimized form (e.g. use <p></p> and not <p />)." - XHTML 1.0, http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xhtml1-20020801/#guidelines

Answer (score 2):

In XHTML `<script />` means "A complete script element" (note, browsers decide if a document is XHTML or HTML based on the content-type HTTP header, not the Doctype).

In HTML `<script />` means "A start tag for a script which starts with a `>` character", but for historical reasons, it gets treated as "A start tag for a script with a funny attribute that I'll ignore".

So, you have a script element that you open, but it doesn't get closed until the `</script>` tag for the *second* script element. The `<style>` element is inside the script, so it gets treated as JavaScript instead of HTML. Since the script specifies a `src` the inline script (including the style element) is ignored.