# xhtml self-closing anchor element <a /> allowed?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

If I make an anchor element and don't want text within it, because I'm gonna to css-i-fy it with a nice image and a hover-effect...
I wonder if it is legal to write `<a id="hoverimage" href="google.com" />`
validome.org & validator.w3.org say **YES** ?

BTW: anyone knows an equivalent to alt element for this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/is-writing-self-closing-tags-for-elements-not-traditionally-empty-bad-practice Here it is :D

Comment: Since W3C's validator tells you it's valid, why still ask? If you want to make a clickable image, place an `<img>` in an `<a>`, then you can give it alt text.

Comment: Are you validating the markup as XHTML? If so, then the answer should be pretty darn clear.

Comment: *(reference)* http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.3, http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6 and http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/guidelines.html#C_3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is [valid in XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-eetag). It is [not HTML-Compatible](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_3) so likely to break in a document served as text/html. Having a link with no content is bad practise (background images are not content (which is why there is no equivalent to the alt attribute)).

Comment: second that. When using an image also give it a text value