# Invalid location of tag (p)

Tags: html, eclipse, tags

I have this code:

```
<p class="pHelp"> xxxxx <a href="#components">Form components</a> yyyyy </p>
```

This line is inside html/body/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/p/#text (<- btw, what is the proper name for this "html's tag route/path"?)

Eclipse gives me an Other error on that line. How should I solve this?

It also complains about this sentence...

```
<a id="pd" /><h5>Provisional Data</h5>
```

...where it indicates 'No end tag (`</a>`).' Aren't self-closing tags allowed in HTML?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064533/xhtml-self-closing-anchor-element-a-allowed

Answer (score 0):

An interactive anchor element must not appear as a descendant of an anchor element. Your code appears to have multiple levels of nesting of anchor elements.

An anchor element must have a start tag and an end tag.

See the [W3C language reference for the anchor element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html).

Answer (score 0):

Only empty elements - that is elements that can't contain anything, such as `img` or `br´ - can use the self-closing syntax, unless you explicitly use an XHTML DOCTYPE, but even then older browsers such as IE<7 don't support that either.

Also you don't need to use a `<a>` element if you just need an id to set an anchor. Just set the ID to any other element, in this case, for example, directly to the `<h5>` element:

```
<h5 id="pd">Provisional Data</h5>
```