# Why my dangerouslySetInnerHTML rendered content is modified?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following `react` code:

```js
const externalMarkup = `
<a data-refpt='DN_0OKF_177480_ID0EMPAC' />
<ol>
    <li value='1'>
        <p>
            <strong>Some Title</strong>
        </p>
        <ol>
            <li value='1'>
                <a data-refpt='DN_0OKF_177480_ID0EACAC' />
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non ligula arcu. Nulla lobortis, purus et ultrices interdum, quam velit lobortis quam, blandit fringilla eros mauris at neque. Duis non nisl egestas mi fermentum laoreet. Vivamus ultricies odio sed leo vestibulum pulvinar. Quisque vitae libero sed velit hendrerit rhoncus non in nunc. Donec vulputate ante dolor, at aliquet odio tempus in. Sed orci urna, ullamcorper in nulla tempor, sollicitudin eleifend lectus. Aliquam posuere vel nisl porttitor elementum. Mauris quis dolor sagittis, tempus nunc quis, pharetra lectus. Integer semper laoreet tempor. Proin vel nunc in quam posuere vehicula. Cras sollicitudin dolor eu vehicula laoreet. Etiam lacus diam, tincidunt id congue id, mattis ac tortor. Vestibulum congue vestibulum egestas. Etiam in fermentum quam.</p>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <ol>
            <li value='2'>
                <a data-refpt='DN_0OKF_177480_ID0EODAC' />
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non ligula arcu. Nulla lobortis, purus et ultrices interdum, quam velit lobortis quam, blandit fringilla eros mauris at neque. Duis non nisl egestas mi fermentum laoreet. Vivamus ultricies odio sed leo vestibulum pulvinar. Quisque vitae libero sed velit hendrerit rhoncus non in nunc. Donec vulputate ante dolor, at aliquet odio tempus in. Sed orci urna, ullamcorper in nulla tempor, sollicitudin eleifend lectus. Aliquam posuere vel nisl porttitor elementum. Mauris quis dolor sagittis, tempus nunc quis, pharetra lectus. Integer semper laoreet tempor. Proin vel nunc in quam posuere vehicula. Cras sollicitudin dolor eu vehicula laoreet. Etiam lacus diam, tincidunt id congue id, mattis ac tortor. Vestibulum congue vestibulum egestas. Etiam in fermentum quam.</p>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
`

ReactDOM.render(
  <div className='app'>
    <div className='raw-content'>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: externalMarkup }}></div>
    </div>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/leoseccia/pen/QXjvRj?editors=0011) for it.

The `html` appear to render fine however when I look at it in `DevTools` I get some crazy recursion of elements which differs from the original `html`:
[image: rendered html in devtools]

Why am I experiencing this and how do I rectify it?

Comment: It's probably because of the self closing `<a />` tags. what happens if you change your markup to be `<a></a>` instead?

Comment: @azium - just figured that out too... Should have wrote it as an answer, rather than a comment :)

Comment: well I was asking you a question :p I can write that as an answer now that I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` tags cannot be self-closing according to the html spec, see another answer here [xhtml self-closing anchor element <a /> allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064533/xhtml-self-closing-anchor-element-a-allowed)

Comment: doh... this is indeed the answer: https://codepen.io/leoseccia/pen/vqNZyM?editors=0011