# innerHTML returns different content Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, innerhtml

When I use innerHTML some tags are added to the dom, I don't modify the string so I don't know where they come from.

```
processInitialDocumentResponse(doc: Document) {
 this.footnotes = doc.footnotes;
 console.log(this.footnotes)
}
```

Console log result:

```
<p>Especial para La Ley. Derechos reservados (Ley 11.723)</p>  <p><a  id="#1"  name="#1" />(1) A objeto de soslayar &#8212;mayormente&#8212; la eventual virtualidad de la mora y la configuración de la causal de injurias graves o abandono.</p>  <p><a  id="#2"  name="#2" />(2) Nuestro Derecho Procesal de Familia, págs. 145/8, Abeledo Perrot, 2ª edición, y nuestro Código Procesal Civil y Comercial de la Nación, T° I, pág. 660, Abeledo Perrot, 4ª edición.</p>  <p><a  id="#3"  name="#3" />(3) VERDAGUER, Alejandro C., &quot;Acción meramente declarativa&quot;, LA LEY, 1990-D, 594; ZINNY, Jorge H., &quot;La acción meramente declarativa&quot;, LA LEY, 1996-B, 598; RIVERA RÚA, Néstor H., &quot;La llamada 'acción meramente declarativa'&quot;, JA, 1975-721-Doctrina; AGUILAR CARAVÍA, Oscar, &quot;La acción meramente declarativa de certeza en el derecho tributario&quot;, LA LEY, 1985-E, 600; GOZAÍNI, Osvaldo A., &quot;La acción declarativa frente a los principios iura novit curia y de congruencia&quot;, LA LEY, 1999-D, 134; SALGADO, Alí J., &quot;La pretensión de la sentencia meramente declarativa de certeza en la competencia originaria de la Corte Suprema&quot;, LA LEY, 1988-D, 30.</p>  <p><a  id="#4"  name="#4" />(4) CSJN, 29/3/1988, &quot;Colegio San Lucas SRL c. Estado Nacional y otra&quot;, JA, 1988-IV-382.</p>  <p><a  id="#5"  name="#5" />(5) Cám. Nac. Civ., sala A, 14/3/1995, &quot;Gachassin Dutchmann, Gabriela c. Wessels de Coffa, Linda A. y otros&quot;, JA, 1999-I-Síntesis.</p>  <p><a  id="#6"  name="#6" />(6) MORELLO, Augusto M., Constitución y Proceso, págs. 252/253, LexisNexis.</p>  <p><a  id="#7"  name="#7" />(7) Nuestro Código Procesal, T° I, pág. 659.</p>  <p><a  id="#8"  name="#8" />(8) Cám. Nac. Civ., sala A, 15/12/1997, &quot;Zajac, Gloria M. v. Microómnibus Ciudad de Buenos Aires - Línea 59&quot;, DJ, 1999-1-830; Cám. Nac. Civ., sala C, 9/10/1997, &quot;Macheras, Rubén c. Vivas, Roberto A. y otro&quot;, LA LEY, 1998-B, 90; Cám. Nac. Civ., sala G, 4/6/1998, &quot;Ruiz, Damaso c. Limont, Alejandro&quot;, LA LEY, 1999-B, 61; Cám. 2ª Civ. y Com. La Plata, sala I, 30/6/1998, &quot;Maggio, Italo F. c. Línea 18 SRL&quot;, LLBA, 1999-73 o DJBA, 155-355; Cám. Nac. Com., sala B, 3/11/2000, &quot;Cerutti, Roberto A. y otro c. Dota SA de Transportes y otro&quot; y &quot;Federación Patronal Coop. de Seguros Ltda. c. Línea 28, interno 46 y otros&quot;, LA LEY, 2001-B, 42; RCyS, 2001-II-155; Cám. Nac. Com., sala D, 30/11/1998, &quot;Castillo, Oscar H. c. Transportes Automotores Cuyo Ltda. y otro&quot;, LA LEY, 1999-D-242; DJ, 1999-2-1013; Cám. Nac. Com., sala E, 9/3/1999, &quot;Almeida de Estela, Irma c. Empresa Gral. Roca SA y otro&quot;, LA LEY, 1999-F, 55; DJ, 2000-1-586.</p>  <p><a  id="#9"  name="#9" />(9) Ob. y lug. citados en nota 2.</p>  <p><a  id="#10"  name="#10" />(10) C. Civ. y Com. San Isidro, sala 1ª, 09/11/1993, V., S. v. C., M. A., JA 1995-III-44.</p>  <p><a  id="#11"  name="#11" />(11) Si por caso se le imprimiese a la acción declarativa de alimentos las normas del juicio ordinario o, como suele suceder entre nosotros, las de los incidentes, su admisión aparejaría la supresión del efecto devolutivo que el artículo 647 del Código Procesal Civil y Comercial de la Nación acuerda al recurso de apelación deducido contra la sentencia que admite la pretensión de alimentos, y la violación de lo que imperativamente dispone el artículo 376 del Código Civil.</p>  <p><a  id="#12"  name="#12" />(12) Con la vital limitación que marca inicialmente el artículo 644 del Código Procesal en cuanto a que producida la prueba del actor se cierra la etapa probatoria del demandado.</p>  <p><a  id="#13"  name="#13" />(13) O al menos ello debe ser así previsto.</p>  <p><a  id="#14"  name="#14" />(14) Ver nuestro Código Procesal, T° II, pág. 1143/44.</p>  <p><a  id="#15"  name="#15" />(15) Es claro que lo que aquí se propone no excluye la decisión de otras cuestiones conexas, así la fijación cautelar de alimentos máxime que la propia demanda demuestra la existencia de un derecho en grado de verosimilitud, mientras que el peligro resulta &quot;ipsa loquitur&quot;.</p>
```

html component:

```
<div id="document-footnotes">
  <div #footNotes [innerHTML]="footnotes | safeHtml" ></div>
</div>
```

[dom screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umf3a.png)

The elements next to red arrows are created in some moment but I don't know when.
Same happens when I use createElement with renderer and use innerHTML property.

I hope you can help me :)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think angular is choking on the `<a  id="#1"  name="#1" />`. Self-closing anchor tags are problematic. If it's being used just as an anchor, why not put the `id` in the `<p>` tag directly?

```
http://website.com/aboutus.html#gohere
```

will still scroll down to

```
<p id='gohere'>content....</p>
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/8064583/1772933

... update: Since you can't affect the incoming content at the source, maybe you could try closing the tags through regex and see if that helps.

```
this.footnotes = this.footnotes.replace(/<a(.*)\/>/g, '<a$1></a>');>
```

Comment: It is actually a valid identifier in html5 https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: @charlietfl - Thx... wow, I knew it was less strict, but I didn't know it was that loose! I'll edit my response. `<p class="++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.">` LOL!

Comment: Not sure what inspired the spec committee to go that wild

Comment: All those issues are from content area. Unfortunately I don't think they fix them.

Comment: @LuisGutiérrez - I updated my answer. Give that a go, see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks John :) It helps to solve another problem related with this task.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is blocking the content . The shared text contains special charaters and dates as well. YOu will need to parse the content by adding correctly to render it. Try using / or backslash to parse the content

Comment: Hello Soniya and thanks for answer.
I'm not sure if angular if blocking the content. I can see it in the dom and on the page as such.

Comment: Hi Luis, the issue is happening because of the extra white spaces in the innerHTML. I tried to rectify the issue and it has occurring for me as well when I tried the same shared content. However I resolved it by removing the extra white spaces. Please refer the below Stackblitz code. Also, you will surely need to parse the content. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gyc81q?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks so much soniya. I use regular expressions to delete them.