# Javascript file not working on github pages

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

I am able to load my javascript file on the local machine. But on github pages, it is not working.

I have included the file in index.html as

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/JavaScript"/>
```

The website is https://abhikulshrestha22.github.io./

The code is at https://github.com/abhikulshrestha22/abhikulshrestha22.github.io

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**
I tried to add the following code in my javascript file to check if its working, but it is not working on github page and working locally.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("hi");}
```

Comment: its working on my system

Comment: are you getting the alert?

Comment: Try moving your <script src="script.js" type="text/JavaScript"/> to the top of the file, see if it works, and check if jquery and the other script files aren't working.

Comment: It is probably definitely your file isn't loading. Check console to see if theres an error.

Comment: @Lorddirt , In console, i can't see any error of file not loading.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Use closing `script` tag.

For more check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work).

Comment: it works!! but could u please tell why was it working on the local machine then?

Comment: @AbhishekKulshrestha check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/348818/3551786), they have mentioned everything.

Answer (score 3):

`<script>` tags need a closing tag even if it loads an external script.

You forgot it, so it tries to run `</body></html>` instead.

[image]

Comment: it works!! but could u please tell why was it working on the local machine then?

Comment: Did you use the same browser?

Comment: yes. used chrome for both

Comment: Does the html-view in the chrome console look the same?

Comment: A possiblity I can think of would be, that github.io or localhost adds another element after your `<script>` tag and thus forces the script to close. Another possiblity would be that github sends different headers that indicate the file is html so the browser closes the tag.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with wrong spelling.

Try this:

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

I would advise you to move js files in a js directory on the root, following some best practices.