# Java script lazy loading images not working on GitHub website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, github

I am trying to lazy load images onto a GitHub website. I am able to load these images in when I just run the HTML file on my desktop but not on the GitHub website. I have Viewed other questions such as [Javascript file not working on github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261710/javascript-file-not-working-on-github-pages) but this is only for a request from a HTTPS. 
Can anyone help me?

```js
// JavaScript Document
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lazyImages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img.Images"));

  if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
    let lazyImageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
      entries.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          let lazyImage = entry.target;
          lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;
          lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.dataset.srcset;
          lazyImage.classList.remove("Images");
          lazyImageObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
    lazyImage.classList.add("LazyImages");
        }
      });
    });

    lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
      lazyImageObserver.observe(lazyImage);
    });
  } else {
    // Possibly fall back to a more compatible method here
  }
});
```

```css
.Images {
 width: 280px;
 height: 280px;
 padding: 10px;
 object-fit: cover;
}
.LazyImages {
 width: 280px;
 height: 280px;
 padding: 10px;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
    <img class="Images" src="Images/Compressed Images/Insta Photo-90.JPG" data-src="Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-90.JPG" data-srcset="Images/Compressed Images/Insta Photo-90.JPG, Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-90.JPG" alt=""/>
  <img class="Images" src="Images/Compressed Images/Insta Photo-89.JPG" data-src="Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-89.JPG" data-srcset="Images/Compressed Images/Insta Photo-89.JPG, Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-89.JPG" alt=""/>
  <img class="Images" src="Images/Compressed Images/Insta Photo-88.JPG" data-src="Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-88.JPG" data-srcset="Images/Compressed Images/Insta Photo-88.JPG, Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-88.JPG" alt=""/>
  <img class="Images" src="Images/Compressed Images/Insta Photo-87.JPG" data-src="Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-87.JPG" data-srcset="Images/Compressed Images/Insta Photo-87.JPG, Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-87.JPG" alt=""/>
  <img class="Images" src="Images/Compressed Images/Insta Photo-86.JPG" data-src="Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-86.JPG" data-srcset="Images/Compressed Images/Insta Photo-86.JPG, Images/With Out Logo/Insta Photo-86.JPG" alt=""/>
```